# Java Unix client calling NTLM Authenticated REST API

Tags: java, unix, client, ntlm

Google research gives me plenty of articles on implementing NTML server-side security in Java.  My client has the reverse situation.

They have a Java service running on Unix that needs to call our Windows Authenticated C# REST API.  Their attempts so far produce a `401.2 Unauthorized` with the header `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate, NTML`.

What Java library or tutorial will help provide the Windows credentials required for the Unix Java service to make the call?